# PHP MySQL - Database has relation ids in array, but php not showing it

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem. I had two columns holiday1, holiday2 and I combined them into one using `update tbl_entries set total_holidays = concat(holiday1, holiday2)` - this works and the result is as expected, my total_holidays is now `Saturday, Sunday`.

I replaced the value `Saturday, Sunday` with 6, 7 using `REPLACE(total_holidays, "Sunday", "7"); REPLACE(total_holidays, "Saturday", "6");`

I created a new table called `all_holiday_types` which will hold the holiday name and id for each type of holiday (example: ID 1 for Monday ... ID 7 for Sunday).

**The Problem**

In my php, what I am trying to do is iterate through the list of holidays in a multiple select, and show the holidays for each record from `total_holidays` column. Clearly this is not happening. The multiple select has selected all items (Monday .. Sunday), but in my database the `total_holidays` field is `6,7` - so technically it must show `Saturday, Sunday`. - **Anyone know what is causing this issue?**

Also, I have done the same thing with other similar columns and they all seem to work. Only this seems to have the problem.

**Below is my code:**

```
 <select class="form-control show-tick" data-plugin="selectpicker" name="total_holidays[]" multiple="multiple">
<?php $inst=explode(",", $data->total_holidays);
      $holidays=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `all_holiday_types`");
      while($holiday=mysql_fetch_object($holidays)){?>
         <option value="<?php echo $holiday->id; ?>" <?php if(in_array($holiday->id, $inst)){ echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $holiday->holiday; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO. Can you use `print_r($inst);` and show us the output?

Comment: Hi, thanks! It shows Array([0] =>)

Comment: Thats probably your problem, its basically empty.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - yes it is empty. I did concat and replace, is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work after trying all the steps again. You have not answered, else I would award you the best answer for getting me headed in the right direction.